# rails models: can be foreign key null?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have an `event` table and a `place` table. Some `events` belongs to some `places`, while others don't. So I decided to create another table: `placed_event` = `events` which belongs to `place`. My question is: should I keep it this way or only have the `placed_event` table and delete `events` table, so that some `placed_events` will have foreign key `null` - i.e. would not belong to any place?

Comment: why separate the two models, they are both events, and if an event has a `nil` in the `place_id`, then that makes sense, because it doesn't really belong to a place.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is "it depends."

If events can be in 0 or 1 places, then having an events table with a foreign key to a places table will work fine; as Mohammad said in his comment, if the place_id is null, the event just doesn't have a place.

If events can be spread across more than one place, like a concert with many stages, that's when having a join table would make sense.

Hope that helps.

Comment: yea helps, but I wanna make myself sure - so if I make relational table and the events will have many places through categories (and vice versa), it is still OK if some event wont have place

Comment: or I can do it via has many through, and its ok if event will have many places thru just 1 category ?

Comment: Without knowing more details, either of those would possibly work. What you're looking for is to make sure your data modeling is as complex as you need but no more, or as simple as you can make it but still accommodate your needs; and, that your code is defensive enough to handle things like null places for an event, etc. Does that make sense?

Comment: I want to filter those events/ places according a category they belong , but som friend of mine(RoR expert) said that it's possible

Answer (score 0):

If a place `has_many` events and events `belongs_to` a place, you can always leave `place_id` empty(`nil`). It isn't mandatory for all (or any) associations to be present (unless you explicitly have a validation). You should, of course, check for this in your code so you don't try accessing data from an association that doesn't exist (i.e. calling `@event.place.name` when `place` is `nil`).